# Powershell - Create Mass AD-USERS

Tags: powershell

I am building up a script to create Mass AD-USers with a csv file.

I am using Powershell for this.

Here is the error message that I get for this command :

```
$UserLogin = ($UserFirstName).Substring(0,1).ToLower + "." + $UserName.ToLower()
```

Error message
Cannot call a method inside a null expression.
To Character Line:10:1

```
$UserLogin = ($UserFirstName).Substring(0,1).ToLower + "." ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    FullyQualifiedErrorId: InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Also when I run my script, it does not put the datas of my csv in Active Directory

Could anyone help me and explain to me how to fix the message error and how to have my csv datas transferred in my Active Directory ?

Comment: Need more clarity. Your variables do not seem to hold any value and thats why you are getting NULL. Try to edit the question and give more details with sample csv.

Answer (score 0):

Good day Emmanuel

It seems like you are getting a **Null exception** what means your variables are empty.

You can try to get the info using the cmdlet `Import-csv`

For example: You have a Csv with few columns --> Name, LastName, Username and Description.

Then you need to import these information to a variable.

```
$users = Import-Csv [Path].users.csv
```

Then you will be able to get the info of these columns with `$users.name` and `$users.username`

Now to fix you problem you should do this:

```
$UserLogin = $users.name.Substring(0,1).ToLower() + "." + $users.username.ToLower()
```

You forgot to add "()" in the first .tolower --> .tolower()

Using me as example:

```
$users
Name Username
---- --------
Juan Quintero

$users.name.Substring(0,1).ToLower() + "." + $Users.username.ToLower()
j.quintero
```